# Debian 10, cant use 2 Network Interfaces at the same time

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, router, routing

**Problem and explanation:**

What I want to do: Setting up the interfaces, so all can be used at the same time.

Problem: I got 3 Interfaces in total. 1 is the LAN Connection and 2 are LTE Connections tethered by phones. I'm testing the Connection via Ping -I (interface name) and only 1 Connection works. The other 2 are not working, I searched for 6 hours but didn't find an answer.

So to get to the question, my problem is that I have 3 interfaces / connections but can only use one of them. And I want to use all three at the same time

---

**Interfaces and explanation:**

The First LTE Connection is enp0s8

The LAN Connection is enp0s9

The Second LTE Connection is enp0s17

So to explain it simply. I have a LAN interface and 2 tethered LTE interfaces and when I try to ping something with the LAN interface (with ping -I [interface name] 1.1.1.1) it doesn't work, it only works on one interface and this is the first LTE Interface. Which is also the first after the loopback interface with the command "ip addr".

-ping -I enp0s8 1.1.1.1 works [First LTE Interface]

-ping -I enp0s9 1.1.1.1 doesn't work [LAN Interface]

-ping -I enp0s17 1.1.1.1 doesn't work [Second LTE Interface]

---

**Information:**

If you need any additional Information, just ask.

Route =

```
default        192.168.42.129    0.0.0.0         enp0s8
10.0.0.0       0.0.0.0           255.255.255.0   enp0s9
172.20.10.0    0.0.0.0           255.255.255.24  enp0s17
192.168.42.0   0.0.0.0           255.255.255.0   enp0s8
```

Interfaces File =

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug enp0s17
iface enp0s17 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug enp0s9
iface enp0s9 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu and used Netplan to fix it.

I put this in the netplan:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s8:
      dhcp4: yes
    enp0s17:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp4-overrides:
        route-metric: 200
```

This is the solution.